# what is correct format to pass Today as work item createdDate parameter

Tags: reporting-services, tfs-reports

I have created data set (as TFS drill through report) using TFSOlap data source which is displaying all bugs based on created date. Now, I want to pass date range as parameter from main report so drill through report displays data for the bugs created between given date range. I am getting error "string.. can not be converted to date type" I am using following formatting expression at drillthrough report parameter:

```html
="[Work Item].[System_CreatedDate].&[" + FORMAT(Parameters!FromWorkItemSystemCreatedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00]"
```

Please let me know what type of expression should be used to avoid error. I tried with using CDate()  instead of FORMAT but still getting problem.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using the T?
Date Time format: **2014-06-19 15:57:38.750**. Since you're mimicking the date as a string, I think it should be a space.

Comment: You might be just missing milliseconds.   This format works for me:    2015-04-22T14:21:44.143     @HannoverFist, the "T" is used when formatting a date time string for MDX queries.

Comment: I learn this format by giving default values to parameter. Parameter displays it's default value something like this "\[Work Item\].\[System_CreatedDate\].&\[2014-12-31T00:00:00\]"
I get format to Date error if I try to format it.